# How can I tell if a drag and drop operation failed?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

It seems to me there is no way to detect whether a drag operation was successful or not, but there must be some way. Suppose that I want to perform a "move" from the source to the destination. If the user releases the mouse over some app or control that cannot accept the drop, how can I tell?

For that matter, how can I tell when the drag is completed at all?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480156/how-do-i-tell-if-a-drag-drop-has-ended-in-winforms), but his solution does not work for me, and `e.Action` is *always* `Continue`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if that can help you, but DoDragDrop method returns final DragDropEffects value.

```
var ret = DoDragDrop( ... );
if(ret == DragDropEffects.None) //not successfull
else // etc.
```

Answer (score 5):

Ah, I think I've got it. Turns out the call to DoDragDrop is actually *synchronous* (how lame), and returns a value of `DragDropEffects`, which is set to `None` if the op fails. So basically this means the app (or at least the UI thread) will be frozen for so long as the user is in the middle of a drag. That does not seem a very elegant solution to me.

Ok cz_dl I see you just posted that very thing so I'll give u the answer.

This I don't understand though: how can the destination determine whether the op should be a move or a copy? Shouldn't that be up to the source app?

Answer (score 0):

Can't add comment yet, so another answer.
I was also surprised when I saw for the first time, that DoDragDrop is called synchronously and it somehow doesn't froze the UI.

But the copy/move stuff I believe is perfectly logical. You can specify allowed effects while calling DoDragDrop method in source app and that's all what's important to you. How destination app will handle and use the data it's up to it.