# Query Dragging state globally in Windows / DragDrop in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm using WPF here, I have some items in a list, which I can drag. As soon as you drag them I use:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, new DragDropCommandItem(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

And animate-in a 'bin' over the UI where you can drag the item if you want to delete it. This all works well, except that I can't seem to do anything to detect when the user released the mouse so that I can hide the 'bin'. The second you call DragDrop.DoDragDrop it appears to release capture of the mouse. So even a system wide mouse down check returns false.

Is there any nice way to do this, or a way to query the drag state?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this... I'll close the question now as I can use this solution.

[How do I tell if a Drag Drop has ended in Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480156/how-do-i-tell-if-a-drag-drop-has-ended-in-winforms)